# Convert any type of encoded input string to UTF-8 with standard .Net functionality / BCL

Tags: .net, string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

In one of our applications users can upload plaintext files into the system and later on these files are read and worked on. Unfortunately users have a wide variety of encodings for these files (Ansi, UTF-*, Unicode, etc etc) but in the end we need the content as UTF-8 strings.

Is there any way to take *any* input string (encoding-wise), identifying its encoding and convert to UTF-8 with .Net standard functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Please, have a read at the following article : http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

tl;dr; version : **It does not make sense to have a string without knowing what encoding it uses.**

Comment: Exactly right; without knowing what you are working with, it could (for example) be any code-page, and you would *never* be able to know which, thus you'd never be able to decode anything > 127. Some files will have BOMs (allowing a fairly educated guess) but that is optional, and not hugely common.

Comment: Mathieu/Marc, ok I re-phrased my question a little - you are obviously right, my question was rather geared towards the use case of allowing the user to provide any file/input & the application shall be able to convert them appropriately to one common encoding, or at least be able to identify the input's encoding and react accordingly (allow certain ones, notify the user about unacceptable ones).

Comment: Still the same issue, having some text without it's encoding is useless. You could try detecting encoding, but it will be guessing, with varying results.

Comment: ["Bush hid the facts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bush_hid_the_facts) is a commonly used example of how guessing an encoding can produce wrong results. Also [something very simple](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx) can have very different meanings in different encodings. Without context information, guessing is just too unreliable, so don't do it. Make your users tell you a file's encoding. If the file doesn't convert right, either the encoding is wrong or the data is wrong. Either way, the user needs to specify the right encoding and/or fix the data.